# Android R file is not auto-generated

Tags: android, file

R file is auto generated but by mistake i have deleted it , how to regenerate it ? Is it possible to me to add contents in it?

Comment: This should be tagged with `android` and not tagged with `r`. The `r` tag refers to the programming language, not a file extension.

Comment: Go to --> Project --> check Build Automatically and Refresh Project.

Comment: If any xml has an error, the R file is not generated back.

Answer (score 4):

Just fix the errors that are stopping the R file from being generated (this is usually a naming issue with xml resource files for me, remember to not use caps in the xml file names), and then clean and build your project.

Also you should never add contents to the R file. Just add what you need in source and resources files and let it auto generate itself.

Answer (score 0):

R file does not allow you to edit or enter your own details is auto generated file.

Answer (score 0):

what to do if R.Java file is deleted after clean project ?

Go to --> Project --> clean project

Comment: sometimes this doesn't help, because there are errors in files that contribute to project resources